# Getting a try catch to continue 'trying' and 1st exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wonder if someone could give me some advice please?

I need to check for the existence of some session variables in asp.net so for instance:

```
try
    {
         zOrder = Session["epdqOrderNo"].ToString();
         zAmount = Session["epdqAmount"].ToString();
         zEmail = Session["epdqEmail"].ToString();
    }
catch
    {

    }
```

Some or all of the session variables may exist and I'm trying to check them all but it appears that the try/catch routine goes into the catch on the first exception that it finds. So in the above example if the session variable `epdqAmount` doesn't exist it won't try and check for `epdqEmail` as its already fell out the try part. So my question is is there any way to stop this behaviour and check all of the variables or should I be using something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the error because `Session["foo"]` will return `null` is there is no session state variable called `foo`, and you can't call `ToString()` on a null reference.

However, you can use [`Convert.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on a null reference (in which case it will simply return `string.Empty`), so you could try this instead:

```
zOrder = Convert.ToString(Session["epdqOrderNo"]);
zAmount = Convert.ToString(Session["epdqAmount"]);
zEmail = Convert.ToString(Session["epdqEmail"]);
```

Using this approach, no `try...catch` is required because exceptions won't get thrown if any of the session variables don't exist.

Comment: Thanks Richard,

Do you mean inside the try/catch or completely deaf off the try/catch?

Comment: Brilliant thanks Richard!

Works a treat.

Thanks to everyone that posted also :)

Comment: It's worth noting that all `Convert.ToString()` does internally is call `ToString` on the object (if the object supports it) with the protection of a `null` check. One caveat is if it actually is `null` it will return `String.Empty` rather than `null`, so you would probably want to use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` in your checks (if you test these variables for a value later).

Comment: @James - I don't think your caveat is correct. I've tested `Convert.ToString(null)` and it returns `null`, not `String.Empty` (despite MSDN claiming otherwise http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/astxcyeh(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @RichardEv that's an interesting find, however, that's probably because the `ToString` overload that's called is not the `Convert.ToString(object)` one, for example, box your `null` to `object` and you should find it returns `""` (and this is the behaviour the OP will see). You will probably find that passing `null` directly results in `ToString(string)` being called which just returns the same value.

Comment: Your statement *"in which case it will simply return `null`"* is only true if the value being passed in is already of type `string`, passing `Session[...]` directly in will result in `String.Empty` being returned because it's boxed as an `object`.

Answer (score 1):

You generally shouldn't `try...catch` in this manner, you could be potentially hiding other problems in your code. Whenever you use a `try...catch` try to be more specific with the exception it is you are after e.g.

```
try
{
}
catch (ErrorICanHandle ex)
{
}
```

Although in your case you would be listening for a `NullReferenceException` which is an indicator that you should really be checking that directly in the code as you would be effectively using exceptions to control your application flow which isn't a good idea.

As to your code, assuming all your session values are of type `string` then all you need is a straight cast

```
zOrder = (string)Session["epdqOrderNo"];
zAmount = (string)Session["epdqAmount"];
zEmail = (string)Session["epdqEmail"];
```

`string` is a special type of value type which inherits from `object` so this would just leave your variable as `null` if there is nothing in the session and not throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   if(Session["MyDataSet"] == null)
{//something}
else
{//something}
```

Answer (score 0):

In *general*, you'd write 3 try/catch blocks.

Couple of notes though:

1. You shouldn't be using a *catch-all* block. You might end up swallowing other important exceptions
2. In your particular case, there are other ways to check whether the session has those variables without throwing an exception, such as a simple null check (`Session["epdqOrderNo"] == null`), so I wouldn't even use try/catch here.

Answer (score -1):

You can assign `""` if they are null as follows using `??` as follow

<del>zOrder = Session["epdqOrderNo"]??"";</del>

```
zOrder = (string) (Session[""] ?? "");
```

Comment: -1 This won't work, `object` isn't a `string` so the types aren't compatible. You would need a cast on either `Session[...]` or `""`.

Comment: Ah my bad, didn't think the `??` would recognize `Session[""]` as a `string` but the cast forces it to `string` - regardless the `?? ""` part isn't needed you may as well just do `(string)Session[""]`.